# How to compile schematron conditions (XPaths/XSLT 2.0) in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, schematron

I want to validate from Java code a schematron condition (which is in the end a xslt boolean evaluation) to know if it is syntactically correct. Our users can provide extra validation rules that we will transform into schematron to validate given XML files, but we want to know if these rules make sense in the end.

I have tried with method compile from javax.xml.xpath.XPath, but seems to lack things like 'castable as' and other default xslt2.0 functions/operators. I've tried to provide a default XPathFuntionResolver to tell the XPath to ignore the functions, but didn't seem to do the trick.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setXPathFunctionResolver(new XPathFunctionResolver() {
    @Override
    public XPathFunction resolveFunction(QName functionName, int arity) {
        return new XPathFunction() {    
            @Override
            public Object evaluate(List args) throws XPathFunctionException {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Which is the best way to validate those user defined rules?

Comment: Assuming you use a certain version of Saxon 9 for your XSLT/XPath/Schematron then in your code you can use e.g. `XPath xpath = new net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl().newXPath();` to use the Saxon implementation of XPath.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a Saxon8 implementation and this also works for this version :D
The only additional thing I had to add was an empty XPathVariableResolver, such as 

`xpath.setXPathVariableResolver(new XPathVariableResolver() {
     public Object resolveVariable(QName arg0) {
   return "";
  }
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `javax.xml.xpath.XPath` in the JDK only supports XPath 1.0, but your particular XPath expressions are XPath 2.0 (or later). There are several third-party implementations of XPath 2.0 available for the Java platform, the Saxon product (mine) is the best known.

You can use Saxon's XPath engine using the standard javax.xml.xpath.XPath API, as Martin Honnen suggests; however the API is designed around XPath 1.0 so it can be tricky to exploit the full functionality of XPath 2.0 (for example, you can't easily evaluate an expression that returns a date). So Saxon has an alternative API called s9api, which is probably easier to use. For details the Saxon documentation is at www.saxonica.com.

Your approach of using a custom function resolver isn't going to help the XPath 1.0 engine understand syntactic constructs like "X castable as Y" - it's only used to resolve function calls.

Comment: I was indeed using Saxon, so @martin-honnen solution worked perfectly. Just added a VariableResolver (I'm certain that we will add some kind of FunctionResolver in the future). Thank to both of you!